# what is the translation of ながら in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

眺めながらキスをしようよ

1. We are kissing while looking at each other.
2. We look at each other and want to kiss.
3. While looking at the view, we wanna kiss each other.
4. After seeing the view, we wanna kiss each other.

I wonder which one is more precise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the options are correct.
"Let's kiss while looking at each other" would be more accurate

互いを眺めながらキスをしようよ would sound more natural imo as it otherwise wouldn't be clear who/what they want to look at

しよう is the causal form of しましょう (which is the volitional form of する)

Other examples of verbs with ながら:
食べながら - While eating
読みながら - While reading
話しながら - While talking
歩きながら - While walking
走りながら - While running

Comment: Thank you for answering. One more question, I looked up 眺め in the dictionary and find that it means the view. So why can it also be used to describe a person? And If using view as the object will be more accurate?

Comment: @Shawmorn 眺める is the word that is being used here. Are you familiar with how ながら works to connect to verbs? Maybe a complete answer should touch on that.

Comment: @Shawmorn I think you've misinterpreted something. 眺め in this sentence is used as a verb, it connects with the ながら so the る part is ommited